# Two types of solution to the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

I have read that we can have two solutions to the second order DE below, where $W$ and $W_p$ are constantants and $\psi$ is a function of $x$: 
$$\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2} = -(W-W_p) \psi $$

---

**(a)** If we define $\mathcal K = \sqrt{W-W_p}$ we get equation:

$$\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} = - \mathcal K^2 \psi$$

---

**(b)** But if we define $\mathcal K = \sqrt{-(W-W_p)}$ we get equation:

$$\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} = \mathcal K^2 \psi$$

---

**QUESTION:** In case (a) the general solution to the DE is supposed to be of a form $\psi=A\sin(\mathcal K x) + B \cos (\mathcal K x)$ While in the case (b) it is supposed to be $\psi = Ce^{\mathcal K x} + De^{-\mathcal K x}$. WHAT determines if we ll get sinusoidal or exponential general solution? Is it the negative sign in front of a $\mathcal K$ that determines this? Or is it $\mathcal K$ itself which is *real* or *imaginary* (this depends on $W<W_p$ or $W>W_p$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W - W_p \ge 0 \Longrightarrow W - W_p = K^2$, thus $K = \sqrt{W - W_p}$ and you can rewrite the equation as follows
$$\psi'' = -K^2\psi$$
having bounded solutions given in the way you already know.

Now, if $W - W_p < 0$, then $-W + W_p > 0$ and therefore $-W + W_p = \widetilde{K}^2$. You can now rewrite the equation as follows
$$\psi'' = \widetilde{K}^2 \psi$$

In this setting it should be clear that the behaviour of the solution depends only on the sign of $W - W_p$.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is the same thing. Notice that
$$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}} {2i}$$
$$\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}} 2$$
$$e^x=\cos(ix)+i\sin(ix)$$
$$e^{-x}=\cos(ix)-i\sin(ix)$$

Comment: Could you be a bit more speciffic?

Comment: @71GA: the two pairs you mentioned are both pairs of fundamental solutions of the differential equation; they span the same space of functions (over ${\bf C}$). Of course, depending on whether $\mathcal K$ is real or imaginary, only one pair will be a pair of real-valued functions for real arguments, but the equation makes perfect sense for complex functions.